# SQL : Select statement order by

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to select a column but with diferent order :

i have 2 table :

table_name:

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
| 1    |    Sindra |
| 2    |    Auli   |
| 3    |    Brian  |
| 4    |    Bina   |
| 5    |    zian   |
| 6    |    Bri    |
| 7    |    Andre  |
+------+-----------+
```

table_temp, id_temp_name foreign key of id(table_name) :

```
+------+--------------+
| id   | id_temp_name |
+------+--------------+
| 1    |    1         |
| 2    |    3         |
| 3    |    4         |
| 4    |    2         |
+------+--------------+
```

with this query :

```
  SELECT  * 
  FROM table_name 
  WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT id_temp_name FROM table_temp)
```

the result is always same look with table_name, i was looking for result that exactly same with id_temp_name order , so the result will be :

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
| 1    |    Sindra |
| 3    |    Brian  |
| 4    |    Bina   |
| 2    |    Auli   |
+------+-----------+
```

thanks for any advice, .

Comment: It's a matter of simple `JOIN`: [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44a28/1).

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewrite the query to be a `JOIN` between both tables, then you can set an ordering based on any column involved, even when not in the final result set:

```
SELECT table_name.id,
       table_name.name
FROM table_name
INNER JOIN table_temp ON table_name.id = table_temp.id_temp_name
ORDER BY table_temp.id ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a join instead of a sub-query.

```
SELECT table_name.id, table_name.name
FROM table_name
INNER JOIN table_temp ON table_name.id = table_temp.id
ORDER BY table_temp.id_temp_name
```

And... usually best to list the fields explicitly instead of using * to select all.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a simple **JOIN** to achieve your result.

Your query:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE id IN 
    (SELECT id_temp_name FROM table_temp)
```

actually returns all the rows and columns of the table_name Table. So you won't get the desired id_temp_name results, since it's in a different table. That's why, you should use **LEFT JOIN**, since your left table is table_name, and your right table is table_temp, and you want to show data from a column of table_temp, which is id_temp_name.

So, what you need to do, is this:

```
    SELECT tn.id, tn.name
    FROM table_name AS tn
    LEFT JOIN table_temp AS tt
    ON tn.id= tt.id_temp_name
    GROUP BY tn.id
```